# Creating Static applicationContext for a shared spring library

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a shared library in spring that would be shared across different spring boot applications.
I would like this shared library to be self contained so I created an applicationContext for this shared library like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="a.b.c")
@PropertySource("classpath:mylib.properties")
public class SpringContext {

}
```

Then, in one of the methods in a  class of this shared library that clients invoke directly,

```
public class SharedLib {

    private static ApplicationContext appContext;

    public void consumersCallDirectly(){
        ApplicationContext ctx = getApplicationContext();
        ClassA clsA = ctx.getBean(ClassA.class);
         ...........
         ............
    }


    private static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
            if (appContext == null) {
                appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringContext.class);
            }
            return appContext;
        }

}
```

I am wondering if using applicationContext as a static variable as I have done in my code is going to have any downside. I don't think of any apart from having difficulties in writing unit tests around global state like this. But apart from that, it seems to solve my purpose pretty well.

Does anyone know of any caveats of this approach is a high transaction/volume type of system ?

Comment: Why do you need application context to be returned in static way? This shared lib's spring components can be easily activated at client side via `@ComponentScan(basePackages="a.b.c")`.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I don't want clients to handle this logic. Moreover, if clients handle this then the beans created from shared library get loaded in to the spring app context of the client and there won't be a separate app context of the shared library.